# A model in a merged PR missing in the database

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Some human models were [merged more than an year ago](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/pull-requests/164/add-models-of-a-person/diff), but today I don't see `person_{standing, walking}` models on http://models.gazebosim.org. I see [e.g. person_standing in source forlder](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_models/src/0e4487a6e1b167e262e6669391efcf3bf21c1c9c/person_standing/?at=default). A few other people sitting next to me are seeing the same and on their Gazebo 2.2.3 on Ubuntu Trusty it's not available even though they have a bunch of other models loaded. Any idea's appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/14813/a-model-in-a-merged-pr-missing-in-the-database/) by [yah130s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1228/yah130s/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 91 on 2016-11-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Thanks for the info. The database should be updated now.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1